# Fingerprint Scanner on Samsung Galaxy Devices

Tags: android, android-studio, samsung-galaxy

in Android Studio, I want to use device's Fingerprint sensor in order to authenticate througth it. Well, I tested my app on many devices and it works everywhere except Samsung Galaxy devices... I tried to search for Samsung Pass SDK but I can no longer find it :/ The links that I found here on StackOverflow answers redirects me to the Samsung Digital ID which I cant access. Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `BiometricPrompt` from the Jetpack should work on those devices. Otherwise, we would need a [mcve] showing the code that you tried and with details of what "it works everywhere except" means.

Comment: Which Samsung Galaxy devices specifically? There are a lot of them. You should also clarify exactly what you mean when you say that it isn't working.

Comment: @Michael Galaxy Note 4

Comment: Well, that device seems to have been launched with Android KitKat. In my experience, devices that originally launched with Android Lollipop or older and had their own fingerprint API often don't support Android's own fingerprint API even after being upgraded to Android Marshmallow. And by extension that means not supporting BiometricPrompt, since BiometricPrompt uses FingerprintManager internally on devices running Android Oreo and older (at least last time I checked). That leaves manufacturer-specific SDKs like Samsung Pass, but I have no idea if or how you still can get those.